# ¿Alguna manera de mandar un STATUS CODE como RESPONSE y que lo tome FAIL de AJAX en JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente formulario solo para validar/hacer pequeñas pruebas con el método ***$.get();*** sobre todo con el botón, pero realmente el formulario lo tengo con el método ***$.ajax();***

```
<form id="form_palabra">
    <div class="mb-3">
       <label for="palabra" class="form-label">
            Palabra
       </label>
       <input type="text" id="palabra" class="form-control" name="palabra" placeholder="Escribe una palabra">
       <div class="form-text">
           Comprobando el manejo de errores en JQuery AJAX
       </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="bg-gradient btn btn-primary">
        Test!
    </button>
</form>
```

La petición con el método ***$.ajax();*** es la siguiente:

```
$('#form_palabra').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'models/pruebas.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
    }).always(function(){
        console.clear();
    }).done(function(response, status){
        if(response.existe_persona == 1){
            console.log(`Hola, mi nombre es ${response.nombre} soy un ${response.genero} de ${response.edad} años de edad`);
        } else {
            console.log("No existe tal persona");
        }
    }).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
    });
 });
```

Manda la petición la manda a ***pruebas.php***, es el siguiente script PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['palabra']) && !empty($_POST['palabra'])){
        $persona = ["nombre" => "Minor", "genero" => "hombre", "edad" => "25"];
        $info_persona['existe_persona'] = 0;
        foreach ($persona as $key => $value){
            $info_persona['existe_persona'] = 0;
            $info_persona[$key] = $value;
        }
        echo json_encode($info_persona);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["mensaje_error" => "No se configuro nada"]);
    }
```

Mis dudas son:

1.- ¿Cómo puedo mejorar mi código? Sí alguna sugerencia que me puedan brindar. (Sé que puedo usar el método ***$.POST();*** pero limita a manejar errores o eso tengo entendido y además no puedes especificar un **dataType**)

2.- ¿Cómo puedo darle un "buen uso o uso correcto" a ***.fail()***? Es decir se manejan los parametros "**jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown**" que muestran el error, code status por ejemplo, pero si quisiera que desde el script PHP mande un status code especifico con/por **Header Request** y lo tome el ***.fail()*** ¿No sé puede o alguna manera? No sé con algun **Web Service**

Digamos que símule un registro de una **database** con el array associativo y quisiera evitar el if dentro del ***.done()*** y que desde el script PHP me diga si hay o no hay registro, entiendo como funciona AJAX JQ pero de una manera sencilla y me tengo duda de como darle "buen uso a .fail()"

O fail es solo para respuesta directa del **server** como un 404 un 500 status code, ya leí la doc, revise varios foros pero sigo con esa duda.

Comment: Es bueno que siempre que se envía una petición desde el front al back regrese un 200, y dejar el fail y demás manejadores de errores que sean errores por conexión o timeout, en el back se debe de trabajar status de true  y codes 200, 400 etc y eso mostrarle al usuario, un ejemplo: supongamos que envías 2 números al back para que se sumen, si todo es correcto regresar un json como {status: true, code: 200, data="respuesta de la suma"} y si hay un error  un json como este {status:false, code:"400", description:"Ambos valores enviados deben ser numéricos"}

Comment: Entonces mando eso en el echo json_encode(status, code); ¿Correcto?

Comment: Tu pregunta no se adapta al formato del sitio, pues está basada en opiniones: *cómo puedo hacer esto o lo otro* ... hay mil formas de hacer cada cosa. Sea como sea, te aconsejo que no reinventes la rueda y que no forces nada. En un entorno de comunicación cliente / servidor lo propio es manejar el flujo en el servidor, respondiendo una estructura lógica que te permita saber lo que ha pasado, algo como un array con una clave `success` que será `true` cuando todo haya sido correcto (hay los datos que esperas) o `false` cuando algo haya fallado **en la lógica**: no conexión, no registros, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. ¿Cómo mejorar el código?

Te sugiero tener una estructura bien definida para devolver como respuesta a la petición AJAX, donde puedas analizar el resultado, datos y, de ser el caso, mensaje de error; por ejemplo:

```
// Crear un arreglo con valores por defecto
$respuesta = [
    'existe' => 0,
    'datos' => [],
    'error' => 'Debes teclear algo para buscar'
];

if(isset($_POST['palabra']) && !empty($_POST['palabra'])) {
    // Para crear un mejor ejemplo, usamos varias personas
    $personas = [
        ["nombre" => "Minor", "genero" => "hombre", "edad" => "25"],
        ["nombre" => "Major", "genero" => "hombre", "edad" => "52"],
        ["nombre" => "Medium", "genero" => "hombre", "edad" => "15"],
    ];
    // Recorrer arreglo de personas
    foreach($personas as $persona) {
        // ¿El nombre de la persona actual es el buscado?
        if($persona['nombre'] == $_POST['palabra']) {
            // Actualizar el arreglo
            $respuesta['existe'] = 1;
            $respuesta['datos'] = $persona;
            $respuesta['error'] = '';
            // Salir del ciclo, no es necesario continuar
            break;
        }
    }
    // ¿No se encontró el nombre?
    if($respuesta['existe'] == 0) {
        // Actualizar error y mensaje de error
        $respuesta['error'] = 'Tu búsqueda no generó resultado';
    }
}
// Devolver el arreglo como JSON
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Seguramente hay formas más simples de hacerlo y, tal vez, debas considerar si quieres hacer distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Ten en cuenta que esto es solo para ilustrar cómo mantener una misma estructura de datos para devolver en cualquiera de los casos:

1. Si no se proporcionó texto para buscar
2. Si se encontró la persona
3. Si no se encontró

### 2. ¿Cómo puedo darle un "buen uso o uso correcto" a .fail()?

Ese método se debe usar solo para controlar errores que no dependen de tu script, cuando no se puede encontrar la URL o hay un error que devuelve estado de petición diferente de 200.

Los errores generados por acciones del usuario deben ser manejados dentro del método `.done()`

```
$('#form_palabra').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Obtener valor a enviar eliminando espacios " Juan " debe ser "Juan"
    let palabra = $('#palabra').val().trim();
    // No enviar si está vacía
    if(palabra == '') {
        // Puede ser una alerta
        console.log('Debes teclear algo para buscar');
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'models/pruebas.php',
        // Enviar solo lo necesario
        data: { palabra: palabra },
        // La propiedad correcta es method
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
    }).always(function() {
        console.clear();
    }).done(function(response) {
        // Analizar el valor recibido
        if(response.existe == 1) {
            // Tomar información de persona desde response.datos
            console.log(`Hola, mi nombre es ${response.datos.nombre} soy ${response.datos.genero} de ${response.datos.edad} años de edad`);
        } else {
            // Mostrar mensaje de error
            console.log(response.error);
        }
    }).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Esto va a aparecer solo en caso de errores de red, servidor, etc.
        // Es decir, cuando no se pueda acceder correctamente a la URL
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Aún no me queda claro eso de "errores generados por acciones del usuario dentro de done()" ¿Se puede mandar un status code en el error por usuario? Por ejemplo mandar un "401: No autorizado" y que lo muestre en el done(), (cosa que en este status code debes mandar las credenciales en metodo ajax()) lo digo por ejemplo porque leí sobre algo como $.done(response, status), ¿Se puede manipular un status code pero que lo reciba done() y no fail()?

Comment: @Minor, no es posible, cualquier estado HTTP que no sea 200 va a ir directo a `.fail()`. En todo caso, crea un elemento `status` dentro del arreglo de respuesta donde puedas poner los códigos que deseas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, entendí todo correctamente, marque tu respuesta como correcta, seguiré investigando un poco más, pero ya con menos duda acerca del tema